# How to set watcher for input.$error object with directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form that contain date inputs and select elements,
I tried to use ngChange but I found it not very useful when handling dates errors.
So I'm trying to set a watcher in a directive for every input.$error in order to display error message to the user.

#### my directive:

```
module.directive('validator', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      scope.input = ctrl;
      scope.$watch('input.$error', function() {
        console.log(scope.input);
      }, true);
    }
  }
}]);
```

The problem with the directive is that the scope.$watch fires only when an error object of dates is changing, and the `scope.input` of every input becomes similar to the `ctrl` of the changed date input.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Liad91/kd91a91t/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deep checking of the directive behavior. I find out that the `scope.input` of the last element infect all the others scopes. 
So I set the $watch to listen to `ctrl.$error`, and it solved the problem.

#### The directive:

```
module.directive('validator', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      scope.$watch(function() {return ctrl.$error}, function() {
        if (ctrl.$invalid) {
            console.log(attr.name, 'invalid');
        }
        else {
            console.log(attr.name, 'valid');
        }
      }, true);
    }
  }
}]);
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Liad91/kd91a91t/1/)

Comment: yes now you can have control on  ctrl.$error object .

Answer (score 1):

Update your directive to watch if the input is invalid

```
 module.directive('validator', [function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^form',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, form) {

      var inputName = attr.name;
      console.log(inputName, form[inputName].$error)
      function watcherForRequired(){
       return form[inputName].$error.required;
      }
      function watcherForMin(){
       return form[inputName].$error.min;
      }
      scope.$watch(watcherForRequired, function(required) {
        console.log("required", required);
      })
      scope.$watch(watcherForMin, function(min) {
        console.log("min error", min);
      })
    }
  }
```

also update ng-min to `min="{{loan.loaned}}"`

here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9u1m2s3/)

Comment: I want to set the watcher for the $error because I want to change the error message dynamically, e.g. when the date error is changing from required to min

Comment: actually error object stores both required and min keys. when min error occurs $error changes to myForm.input.$error = {"min":true}. So you need to watch $error, as you did. But ng-min is only applied when the input type is number. So in date type it doesnt work

Comment: return form[inputName].$error soukd work in your case if tyoe is number

Comment: The ngMin can be either string or date inside input[date] [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D)

Comment: It's working but it's very messy, because in this way I need to set a watcher for every validation that I'll add to the form.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this to display error messages? Why not simply do this in the template?

```
<form name="myform">
  <input ng-model="myform.model.user-name" name="user-name" id="my-form-user-name" />
  <div ng-messages="myform.user-name.$error">
    <p ng-if="myform.user-name.$invalid">My Error Message Here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because I want to use tooltips to display the errors